# Swagger api-docs to swagger.json?

Tags: swagger, spray

I'm using Spray with the latest version of spray-swagger (0.5.1) and I can see my API documentation in swagger-ui just fine. But spray-swagger uses a hierarchical directory structure that starts at /api-docs...I want to use other swagger related tools and those tools seem to prefer a single swagger.json file.

Is there any tools to convert from /api-docs hierarchical directory structure to a single swagger.json file ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Swagger Converter](https://github.com/apigee-127/swagger-converter). Here is an example provided in their page:

```
var convert = require('swagger-converter');

var resourceListing = require('/path/to/petstore/index.json');

var apiDeclarations = [
  require('/path/to/petstore/pet.json'),
  require('/path/to/petstore/user.json'),
  require('/path/to/petstore/store.json')
];

var swagger2Document = convert(resourceListing, apiDeclarations);

console.log(swagger2Document);
```

Comment: Can this function when the resourceListing is at /api-docs ? ( http://127.0.0.1:8080/api-docs ) I get the following error from node:Error: Cannot find module 'http://127.0.0.1:8080/api-docs'

Comment: I'm not sure if the `convert` function support URLs. If it doesn't, you will have to download the files (e.g. api-docs) to your local drive before performing the conversion.